# paginator count all records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Does CakePHP PaginatorHelper have a function for getting a record count (all records in the table, not only on this page)? Like mysql's `COUNT()` or PHP's `mysql_num_rows()`.

Or i should use the controller's `find()` function?

Thanks, a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**counter()**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#pagination-in-views) method can be used for that.

```
echo $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => '{:count}'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use/overwrite `paginageCount`: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/249/Custom-Query-Pagination